# OpenVPN client-client seems to not work (client can see only server)

Tags: openvpn

I configured OpenVPN server with tun device.

My problem is that each client cannot see the rest of the clients.

For tests I turned off all firewalls to exclude problem with firewall rules.

Every help or even suggestions and comment are welcome. Currently I'm out of ideas.

---

**Server configuration**:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

client-to-client
duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

cipher DES-EDE3-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 15

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn-status.log

verb 5
```

---

**Client configuration**:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp

remote myserver.com 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

ca keys/ca.crt
cert keys/client01.crt
key keys/client01.key
ns-cert-type server
tls-timeout 20
cipher DES-EDE3-CBC  # Triple-DES

comp-lzo
verb 3
```

---

**Server routing table for tun0**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

---

**Client routing table for tun0**:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

Comment: Im almost in 100% sure this is a problem with routes.

Comment: I inlined your pastebin links - we recommend including the question body (if it's not too large) rather than linking outside the site.

Comment: ehhh, it was a firewall issue. I was informed that there is another mysterious firewall who blocked openVPN connection. Now it works like a charm. Thank you guys for support.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side it should be:

```
10.0.99.9       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.0.99.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
```

On the server side it should be:

```
10.0.99.2       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.0.99.0       10.0.99.2       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

In the above example:

- 10.0.99.9 is the clients IP-address on the tun0 interface.
- 10.0.99.1 is the servers IP-address on the tun0 interface.

What are your ip-addresses on client and server side tun0 interface?

Comment: on server side we have " inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255" and on client side we have "inet addr:10.8.0.2  P-t-P:10.8.0.1  Mask:255.255.255.255" third client has almost the same setup like client02 (only ip address is different). Of course my goal is to ping client02 from client03 for example.